# Sum $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}x^{n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, solution-verification, geometric-series

I want to find the sum function of the series

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}x^{n} $$

and I would like to get your assessment of my work cause I'm really not sure about its validity?

I define the sum $$s(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}x^{n}$$ and multipy with x

$$ s(x)\cdot x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}x^{n+1}  $$

then differentiate

$$ (s(x)\cdot x)' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n}  $$

divide by x

$$ \frac{(s(x)\cdot x)'}{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}  $$

then integrate and find the sum of a regular geometric series

$$ \int\frac{(s(x)\cdot x)'}{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}  $$

differentiate again

$$ (\int\frac{(s(x)\cdot x)'}{x})' = (\frac{1}{1-x})' \Rightarrow \frac{(s(x)\cdot x)'}{x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{2}} $$

multiply by x and take the integral

$$ s(x)\cdot x = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{t}{(1-t)^{2}}dt = \ln(|x-1|) - \frac{1}{x-1} + C $$

To find the constant C let $x=0$ and find that $C=-1$. Lastly divide by x to get the final result

$$ s(x) = \frac{\ln(|x-1|)}{x} - \frac{1}{x(x-1)} - \frac{1}{x} $$

Can anyone verify that this is correct? Or is there another way to get the sum?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider $\frac{n}{n+1} = \frac{n+1}{n+1} - \frac1{n+1}$. Might make it easier to split up like that from the start.

Comment: Yes that could also be a viable option, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Related [Find a function for the infinite sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1}x^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1730216)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. But there is a simpler way. Note that\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac n{n+1}x^n&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+1}\\&=\frac1{1-x}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+1}.\end{align}In order to compute$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n+1},$$if $s(x)$ is its sum, then$$\bigl(xs(x)\bigr)'=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$$and therefore $xs(x)=-\log|x-1|$. So, the sum of your series is$$\frac1{1-x}+\frac{\log|x-1|}x.$$

Comment: Thanks José, that was a neat trick!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: If you consider where the thing converges, don't you get rid of the absolute value?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes, that is correct. It converges on $[-1,1)$ and its sum is$$\frac1{1-x}-\frac{\log(1-x)}x$$there.